# Are there smart collars for dogs?

Tags: dogs, containment, collar

Is there a smart collar that keeps your dog in a perimeter by shock and leash pull simulation? I am looking for something a lot like Petelligent, but they went out of business. I am looking for something that does a lot of the same things.

Comment: Please update your question with the type of dog you have and what functions you are trying to do. Someone may be able to suggest a collar or a combination of training and physical infrastructure that can do the same thing.